# Why doesn't "osinfo-query os" detect Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

OS: Kubuntu 18.04.1 (and Ubuntu 18.04.1 in a virtual machine)

When I run `osinfo-query os` after installing `libosinfo-bin`, the output doesn't include Ubuntu 18.04:

```
$ osinfo-query os | grep -i ubuntu | cut -d ' ' -f -2
 ubuntu10.04
 ubuntu10.10
 ubuntu11.04
 ubuntu11.10
 ubuntu12.04
 ubuntu12.10
 ubuntu13.04
 ubuntu13.10
 ubuntu14.04
 ubuntu14.10
 ubuntu15.04
 ubuntu15.10
 ubuntu16.04
 ubuntu16.10
 ubuntu17.04
 ubuntu17.10
 ubuntu4.10
 ubuntu5.04
 ubuntu5.10
 ubuntu6.06
 ubuntu6.10
 ubuntu7.04
 ubuntu7.10
 ubuntu8.04
 ubuntu8.10
 ubuntu9.04
 ubuntu9.10
$
```

Why is that? And can I somehow update something to get Ubuntu 18.04 included?

The reason I'm asking is because of:

> Next we passed the `--os-variant` option. While this is not mandatory, is highly recommended to use it, since it can improve performance of the virtual machine. The option will try to fine tune the guest to the specific OS version. If the option is not passed, the program will attempt to auto-detect the correct value from the installation media.

which I read in [How to create and manage KVM virtual machines from CLI](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-and-manage-kvm-virtual-machines-from-cli).

In response to [Rinzwind's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1070510/248158), the output of `locate` after running `sudo updatedb` is:

```
$ locate libosinfo
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libosinfo-1.0.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libosinfo-1.0.so.0.1001.0
/usr/share/doc/gir1.2-libosinfo-1.0
/usr/share/doc/libosinfo-1.0-0
/usr/share/doc/libosinfo-bin
/usr/share/doc/gir1.2-libosinfo-1.0/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/gir1.2-libosinfo-1.0/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libosinfo-1.0-0/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/libosinfo-1.0-0/README
/usr/share/doc/libosinfo-1.0-0/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libosinfo-1.0-0/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libosinfo-bin/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libosinfo-bin/copyright
/var/cache/apt/archives/libosinfo-bin_1.1.0-1_amd64.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gir1.2-libosinfo-1.0:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gir1.2-libosinfo-1.0:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libosinfo-1.0-0:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libosinfo-1.0-0:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libosinfo-1.0-0:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libosinfo-1.0-0:amd64.symbols
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libosinfo-1.0-0:amd64.triggers
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libosinfo-bin.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libosinfo-bin.md5sums
```

Neither `/usr/share/libosinfo/db` or `/etc/libosinfo/db` are present.

---

Running `locate os-info` as suggested by Rinzwind did the job:

```
$ locate osinfo | grep ubuntu
/usr/share/osinfo/install-script/ubuntu.com
/usr/share/osinfo/install-script/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-preseed-jeos.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-10.04.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-10.10.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-11.04.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-11.10.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-12.04.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-12.10.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-13.04.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-13.10.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-14.04.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-14.10.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-15.04.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-15.10.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-16.04.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-16.10.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-17.04.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-17.10.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-4.10.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-5.04.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-5.10.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-6.06.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-6.10.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-7.04.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-7.10.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-8.04.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-8.10.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-9.04.xml
/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-9.10.xml
$
```

It should now be easy to add `/usr/share/osinfo/os/ubuntu.com/ubuntu-18.04.xml`. Though it still leaves open the question of why it wasn't included in the first place.

Comment: I tried copying the 17.10.xml and editing it. Way too much info in there.  Found it easier from the GitLab and just replace them.  I did edit my answer a lot this morning as this was the first time I messed with the `osinfo` but I think I got something that works.

Comment: Because time travel hasn't been invented yet, 18.04 shipped with an osinfo-db that did not include it. Hopefully they will update it at some point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could always take it from the [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/libosinfo/osinfo-db) site then replace it.

Might need to install the `git`, `osinfo-db-tools`, `intltool` and `make` first

```
sudo apt install osinfo-db-tools intltool make git
```

Clone the osinfo from the GitLab page

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/libosinfo/osinfo-db
```

Go to the `osinfo-db` folder

```
cd osinfo-db/
```

Prepared the os files

```
./prepare-release.sh
```

During the prepare it showed the following line:

```
osinfo-db-import --root /home/terrance/builder --system osinfo-db-20180830.tar.xz
```

So, I went to that folder `cd ~/builder` and it contained a `usr` folder.  All I had to do was copy that folder to the root and it updated

```
cd ~/builder
sudo cp -Rv * /
```

And now it detects Ubuntu 18.04

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~/builder$ osinfo-query os | grep -i ubuntu
 ubuntu10.04          | Ubuntu 10.04 LTS                                   | 10.04    | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/10.04          
 ubuntu10.10          | Ubuntu 10.10                                       | 10.10    | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/10.10          
 ubuntu11.04          | Ubuntu 11.04                                       | 11.04    | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/11.04          
 ubuntu11.10          | Ubuntu 11.10                                       | 11.10    | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/11.10          
 ubuntu12.04          | Ubuntu 12.04 LTS                                   | 12.04    | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/12.04          
 ubuntu12.10          | Ubuntu 12.10                                       | 12.10    | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/12.10          
 ubuntu13.04          | Ubuntu 13.04                                       | 13.04    | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/13.04          
 ubuntu13.10          | Ubuntu 13.10                                       | 13.10    | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/13.10          
 ubuntu14.04          | Ubuntu 14.04 LTS                                   | 14.04    | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/14.04          
 ubuntu14.10          | Ubuntu 14.10                                       | 14.10    | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/14.10          
 ubuntu15.04          | Ubuntu 15.04                                       | 15.04    | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/15.04          
 ubuntu15.10          | Ubuntu 15.10                                       | 15.10    | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/15.10          
 ubuntu16.04          | Ubuntu 16.04                                       | 16.04    | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/16.04          
 ubuntu16.10          | Ubuntu 16.10                                       | 16.10    | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/16.10          
 ubuntu17.04          | Ubuntu 17.04                                       | 17.04    | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/17.04          
 ubuntu17.10          | Ubuntu 17.10                                       | 17.10    | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/17.10          
 ubuntu18.04          | Ubuntu 18.04 LTS                                   | 18.04    | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/18.04          
 ubuntu4.10           | Ubuntu 4.10                                        | 4.10     | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/4.10           
 ubuntu5.04           | Ubuntu 5.04                                        | 5.04     | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/5.04           
 ubuntu5.10           | Ubuntu 5.10                                        | 5.10     | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/5.10           
 ubuntu6.06           | Ubuntu 6.06 LTS                                    | 6.06     | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/6.06           
 ubuntu6.10           | Ubuntu 6.10                                        | 6.10     | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/6.10           
 ubuntu7.04           | Ubuntu 7.04                                        | 7.04     | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/7.04           
 ubuntu7.10           | Ubuntu 7.10                                        | 7.10     | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/7.10           
 ubuntu8.04           | Ubuntu 8.04 LTS                                    | 8.04     | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/8.04           
 ubuntu8.10           | Ubuntu 8.10                                        | 8.10     | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/8.10           
 ubuntu9.04           | Ubuntu 9.04                                        | 9.04     | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/9.04           
 ubuntu9.10           | Ubuntu 9.10                                        | 9.10     | http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/9.10
```

Comment: the tests our failing the build

Answer (score 10):

To update the osinfo database, which is actually just a collection of XML files, do the following:

**1:** Install package `osinfo-db-tools` to get the `osinfo-db-import` program (at least on Debian'ish distros):

```
apt update;apt install osinfo-db-tools
```

**2:** Download the newest osinfo-db file from [releases.pagure.org](https://releases.pagure.org/libosinfo/) example:

```
wget -O "/tmp/osinfo-db.tar.xz" "https://releases.pagure.org/libosinfo/osinfo-db-20200325.tar.xz"
```

**3:** Import the downloaded osinfo-db file:

```
osinfo-db-import --local "/tmp/osinfo-db.tar.xz"
```

The new osinfo-db XML files will be located in `/etc/osinfo/..`

The osinfo-db XML files provided by the original distro package are still located in `/usr/share/osinfo`.

The newly path created by `osinfo-db-import` take precedens of the original path.

If you want to overwrite the original osinfo-db XMLs use the option `--system` instead of `--local`

([source](https://libosinfo.org/download/))

Comment: `osinfo-db-import` also supports a third option called `--user`, which allows the info to be used by an unprivileged local user without affecting other users

Answer (score 4):

Because it is not available in the XML that provides this information. It is taken from 1 of these locations:

```
/usr/share/libosinfo/db
/etc/libosinfo/db
${HOME}/.config/libosinfo/db
```

(the 1st one I guessed ;) )

You can add a file ending on ".xml" in `${HOME}/.config/libosinfo/db` and it will be included. Contents of it could be copied from a current already available OS.

---

The location of the file seems to have changed through the years. This is also possible:
|

> User location
>
> This is determined by the env variable

```
$OSINFO_USER_DIR
```

> If not set, then defaults to $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/osinfo If that is not set, then defaults to $HOME/.config/osinfo This location is intended for use by unprivileged users wishing to install local data for use by their applications

Comment: I edited my question because I couldn't find `libosinfo/db` in either of the two suggested locations.

Comment: Do you have a `/etc/osinfo`? or a `$HOME/.config/osinfo`?

Comment: Yes, thanks! `locate osinfo` churned out quite a lot. I'll add that to my question.

Comment: The default $OSINFO_USER_DIR has changed again since this answer was written, so that `libosinfo/db` seems to be deprecated. Using `osinfo-db-import` (as mentioned in @MrCalvin 's answer) with its `--user` option is probably the best way to always find the right place.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install osinfo-db-tools intltool make git
git clone https://gitlab.com/libosinfo/osinfo-db
cd osinfo-db/
./prepare-release.sh
```

pytest give faild
test_urls.py is not connection some repository (fedora36, silverblue37 and opensusetumbleweed) when I use bash script prepare-release.sh

```
FAILED tests/test_urls.py::test_urls[fedora36] - requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='fedora.ip-connect.vn.ua', port=443)
```

Comment: This is a Ubuntu only site so how does this info on other OS help?

Comment: You right, but when I try to install to give this error.! Only I want to install file script "prepare-release.sh".

I use Ubuntu and Debian. do not use Fedora